# Good resources to learn MacRuby

Tags: ruby, cocoa, macos, macruby

I do not know Ruby and I am interested to learn MacRuby.
What would you recommend as your best resource (books, blogs, sites)?
Found:http://www.macruby.org/

More info her from rubyconf.org [Macruby talk](http://merbist.com/2010/11/12/rubyconf-2010-macruby-talk)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [MacRuby: The Definitive Guide](http://macruby.labs.oreilly.com/index.html), by Matt Aimonetti
 very helpful for getting started with MacRuby.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know ruby then these 3 books will bring you up to speed relatively quickly.  The nice thing is that you can use "Design Patterns in Ruby" as your primary text and the other 2 as reference texts (although you should definitely read "The Ruby Programming Language" all the way through at some point):

1. [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177)
2. [The Pickaxe Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356085)
3. [Design Patterns in Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452)

Comment: Thank you +1. New on Ruby. Will start with Design pattern in Ruby

Comment: +1 for "The Ruby Programming Language", excellent book! But IMO Pickaxe is overrated. Design Patterns in Ruby is also a fantastic book.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoyed [Why's (poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) for getting started with Ruby.  Go "chunky bacon"!

Comment: +1 "Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby" is very interesting